# How to change voice in Text to Speech Recognization?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I create Text to Speech application which work normally but my problem is that i need
to change voice nation wise.Suppose now speech in U.S. English and i want to convert it in   Indian language.And also from women voice to men voice.
I try to find relevant answer but i didn't found anything.Please provide me some link,
Tutorial or code.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want User speaks in english, android recognizes it, and then the app speaks in Indian?

Comment: User enter data then apps speak in Indian English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the voice of Android Text to Speech. You can use TextToSpeech.setPitch(), however it only distorts the voice.

You can change the language TextToSpeech uses language by using TextToSpeech.setLanguage(). Just pass in the Locale of the language you want to use.

You can also set the language of the SpeechRecognizer to be any language you want such as English.

In terms of getting things working, here is my example code that uses both TextToSpeech and SpeechRecognition.

[Sample code](https://github.com/gmilette/Say-the-Magic-Word-)

Comment: I need to set or use Indian English but it's not available in Locale..How to i use this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at RecognizerIntent. "String ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH Starts an activity that will prompt the user for speech and sends it through a speech recognizer."

and you can also see this link

Android Speech Input:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html

Android voice recognition API example:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html